# (GCP) ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 354778943856@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to upload a docker image to **GCR(Google Container Registry)** with **Cloud Shell** but I got this error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT:
> could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403:
> 354778943856@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have
> storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.,
> forbidden

This is the steps which I've done.

**(1st step)** I ran this command:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my_project_id/hello_world
```

**(2nd step)** Then, I was asked whether or not enabling and retrying **"API [cloudbuild.googleapis.com]"** then, I put and ran **"y"**:

> Creating temporary tarball archive of 2 file(s) totalling 478 bytes
> before compression. Uploading tarball of [.] to
> [gs://my_project_id_cloudbuild/source/1642137449.192753-983fc894e2f24fa086f55fa3b56d58aa.tgz]
> API [cloudbuild.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [354778943856].
> Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)?
> (y/N)?  y

**(3rd step)** Finally, I got this message with the error message:

> Enabling service [cloudbuild.googleapis.com] on project
> [354778943856]... Operation
> "operations/acf.p2-354778943856-e99f6fd8-78ec-4cbd-94a2-07e0697d5455"
> finished successfully. ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT:
> could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403:
> 354778943856@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have
> storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.,
> forbidden

Even though I enabled **"API [cloudbuild.googleapis.com]"** by running **"y"**, I got the error message.

> ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT:
> could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403:
> 354778943856@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have
> storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.,
> forbidden

Are there any ways to solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you find the message below at the end of the message of **2nd step**?:

> Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)?
> (y/N)?  y

As the message says, it takes **a few minutes** after enabling **"API [cloudbuild.googleapis.com]"** by running **"y"**.

So run the command again a few minutes after enabling **"API [cloudbuild.googleapis.com]"** by running **"y"**:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my_project_id/hello_world
```

Then, it will be successful:

> ID: f4478e51-557b-407d-9c30-c379ef707258 CREATE_TIME:
> 2022-01-14T05:22:29+00:00 DURATION: 19S SOURCE:
> gs://my_project_id_cloudbuild/source/1642137748.745566-d75b61b6c6bc4acb9aba900650f201b2.tgz
> IMAGES: gcr.io/my_project_id/hello_world(+1 more) STATUS: SUCCESS